# Cannot find solution for ,,Load balancer does not have available server for client" with Zuul

Tags: java, spring-boot, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

For a couple of days I am trying to resolve the ,,Forwarding error - Load balancer does not have available server for client" error. Even though this is a common problem with configuring Eureka server and Zuul I cannot find a solution for my problem. There were couple of possibilities to resolve my problem, but none of them seems to work. What I found on the internet and what I've tried:

1. First solution was that @EnableEurekaClient was absent, but I got this annotation from the begining.
2. Second solution was with setting ribbon timeouts, but despite of setting the ribbon and hystrix timeouts it still didnt work out.
3. Third solution that I've found was that fetch-registry was set to false, but also this time I've got it set on true.
4. Last solution was that someone had spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client dependency instead of spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client which provides the ribbon. But unfortunetely that wasn't the case either.

I really don't know what can be wrong, so I ask for help. Moreover when I configured FeignClients on my client microservices they communicated with themself using Eureka without any problem. What I mean by that is that I could send a request from one microservice to another by using for example this url: http://microservice-name/api/v1/... so I guess the problem is with ZUUL.

I think worth mentioning is that I use Spring Security and HTTPS self certificate, but I don't think that it's the case, because when I configure ZUUL module .yml file to "discover" microservices based on their url, everything works just fine.

### There is full stack trace of the problem

I pasted full stack trace on pastebin because it was too long for here. Here's the link [pastebin-full-stacktrace](https://pastebin.com/M2nuaSiH).

These are main 2 lines from stacktrace:

```
com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error
Caused by: com.netflix.client.ClientException: Load balancer does not have available server for client: book-module
```

### There is my ZUUL microservice .yml file with ZUUL and eureka configuration

```
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      uri: 
      database: users_db
  application:
    name: API-Gateway
  mail:
    host: smtp.mailtrap.io
    port: 2525
    username: 
    password: 
    protocol: smtp

server:
  port: 8443
  ssl:
    key-store: classpath:https-springboot.jks
    key-store-password: password
    key-store-type: JKS
    key-alias: https-springboot
    key-password: password

app:
  security:
    secretKey: 942P43hf2bnfrepqaskJfsj09fq2JFdeEKAFDMKmfl2FD
    expirationTime: 600

eureka:
  client:
    fetch-registry: true
    register-with-eureka: false
    service-url:
      default-zone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
  instance:
    hostname: localhost

zuul:
  host:
    connect-timeout-millis: 600000
    socket-timeout-millis: 600000
  ignored-services: '*'
  prefix: /api/v1
  routes:
    author-module:
#      url: http://localhost:8081
      path: /authors/**
      service-id: author-module
    book-module:
#      url: http://localhost:8082
      path: /books/**
      service-id: book-module
    user-module:
#      url: http://localhost:8083
      path: /users/**
      service-id: user-module

springdoc:
  swagger-ui:
    path: "/v3/api-docs/index.html"
    disable-swagger-default-url: true

hystrix:
  command:
    default:
      execution:
        isolation:
          thread:
            timeoutInMilliseconds: 150000

ribbon:
  ConnectTimeout: 6000
  ReadTimeout: 6000
  eureka:
    enabled: true

logging:
  level:
    web: TRACE
    org.springframework:
      web: TRACE
```

### There are it's dependencies

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Auth-module</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Auth-module</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

### There is my example microservice module configuration that I'am trying to connect with

```
    spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      uri: 
      database: authors_db
  application:
    name: author-module

eureka:
  client:
    fetch-registry: true
    register-with-eureka: true
    service-url:
      default-zone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
  instance:
    hostname: localhost

server:
  port: 8081

logging:
  level:
    web: TRACE
    org.springframework:
      web: TRACE
```

### There are it's dependencies

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Author-module</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Author-module</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Please help, I really don't know what to do more.